# Python TensorFlow: train a word2vec model with vector inputs and outputs

Tags: python, input, output, tensorflow, word2vec

I am new to word2vec and tensorflow. I want to train a word2vec model using TensorFlow on Python.

I have studied the [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) from tensorflow. In this training process, the inputs and outputs are simply represented by **index**, which in essence is an **integer** (from my understanding). However, in my case, I want to represent inputs and outputs by **vector**. This vector can be **one-hot encoded** vector or other vectors after some designed manipulation.

I studied some functions such as `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`, `tf.nn.nce_loss`, and etc which are called in the training process, but I was wondering these functions only work with the case of **index**. Would it be possible to work with **vectors** as I wish and at the same time, I can basically utilize the same code structure in [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py)?

If this is impossible, then do you have any good idea to realize the model training with vectors as input and output?